# In TPPDF I would like to add drawing graphics to a document page using PDFKit

Tags: tppdf

Would like to be able to add drawing graphics using PDFKit as a watermark for each page of my report. Is there a supported way of doing that or any equivilent method in TPPDF

Comment: Looking at the source code, I realize that everything is at the CoreGraphics level. I am looking to create graphics at the page-level that are independent (not part of column/line flow). I was hoping to get some insight through this forum. In lieu of an answer I will dig into the code more and figure it out. I report back on my progress. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve the desired goal by adding a delegate to the PDFGenerator class and expoing some of the internal graphics properties and methods. I used the file PDFGenerator+Debug.swift as a guide.